Using data store agents, is there any way to pass parameters or additional data to the generative fallback?
I need to pass a larger amount of text to the query, that is very limited.
I could not find anyway to pass data into the generative fallback template.
I need this to be done from the dialogflow API.
I did succeed in passing a session parameter, yet could not access it via the template. I tried using webhooks, but it did not take that info into account as well.
My goal is that the agent will take into account, when answering me, ny grounded data, my query text and additional data I am dynamically adding in anyway, to bypass the query size limitation.

Did you evaluate using a generator instead of generative fallback? A generator can achieve the same as generative fallback but allows to inject data and check the output before returning it.

I am using a chat app with a grounded data-store, that is its core knowledge, I did not see an option using generators to use a custom data-store. Is there any way I can make this "No Code" solution relate to dynamic addiotnal data, via session parameters, web-hooks... or any other way?
